# Why ${(a^2)}^{\frac 12}=\sqrt {a^2}=|a| \neq a$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

Let $a\in \mathbb R$. It should be true that $\sqrt {a^2}=|a|$, since $\sqrt {(-2)^2}=\sqrt{2^2}=2$ and so on. But, it is also true that ${(a^2)}^{\frac 12}=a$, and by definition, ${(a^2)}^{\frac 12}=\sqrt {a^2}=|a|$. Therefore, $a=|a|$, which is not true. So where is the problem?

Comment: By definition ${\left(a^2\right)}^{\frac 12}=e^{\frac 1 2 \log \left(a^2\right)}$ and the RHS is, of course, equal to $e^{\frac 1 2 \log \left((-a)^2\right)}$. Thus,saying ${\left(a^2\right)}^{\frac 12}=a$ is wrong.

Comment: No it is not true that a^1/2 =\/a.

Comment: @SatvikMashkaria what cha saying?

Comment: It is not true that $(a^2)^{1/2} = a$. Consider $a = -1$. The law $(a^b)^c = a^(bc)$ is only reliable when $a$ is positive and real.

Comment: @HenrySwanson Ah,now I see

Comment: I always thought that $\left(a^2\right)^{1/2}=|a|$. Generally, in high school algebra they assume that all variables are positive real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the equality
$$
\sqrt{a^2}=|a|
$$
is correct, because, by definition, the square root of $x$ is the (unique) *non negative* real number $y$ such that $y^2=x$. Of course we need $x\ge0$ as well, because if $x<0$ there's no number $y$ such that $y^2=x$. Now,
$$
|a|^2=a^2
$$
is clear: if $a\ge0$ we have $|a|^2=a^2$; if $a<0$, then $|a|^2=(-a)^2=a^2$.

You can't argue that $-2=2$ from this fact, because $\sqrt{4}=2$, not $-2$.

Why is this the definition? Because we want to be able to do algebraic manipulations with square roots, so we need a definite result.

Don't confuse it with the search for solutions of the equation $x^2=2$; here we want to find the numbers that, squared, are $2$. So the solutions of the equations are $x=\sqrt{2}$ and $x=-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: But does $((-2)^2)^{1/2} =-2$ ?

Comment: @TomCollinge No; why don't you read the definition?

Comment: Ok. Then the resolution of the OP question is : ${(a^2)}^{\frac 12}=a$ is only true for $a \ge 0$

Comment: Does anybody remember RTFM.